# How I can start an android application after installation in a chromebook using mdm

Tags: android, mdm, chromebook

I developped an android application which has to run on chromebooks.

I will be install it in mdm to avoid install it manually chromebook by chromebook.

This application wait alerts sent by a server. So, users has no action to do when the application starts. There is no screen. The authentification is done in background.

I want to start this application automatically after the installation without user action. But I don't know what I can do it.

Does somebody has an idea? I hope, I am clear

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: developped an android application which has to run on chrome os system.

I will be install it in mdm avoid install it manually chromebook devicesby chromebook.

This application wait alerts sent by a server. So, users has no action to do when the application starts. There is no screen. The authentification is done in background.

I want to start this application automatically after the setup without user action but I don't know what I can do it.

Does somebody has an idea? I hope, I am clear